# How do I access the HTTP request?

Tags: rest, jersey

Say normally I have a REST method in Java

```
@POST 
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String showTime(@FormParam("username") String userName) {

:
:
:
}
```

which is fine. However, I'm wondering is there a way I can access the full HTTP request with Jersey such as

```
@POST 
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String showTime(@FormParam("username") String userName,@XXXXXX String httpRequest) {

:
:
:
}
```

where some annotation would give me the full HTTP request to store in a variable. I have tried using @POST but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 55):

You can use the @Context annotation:

```
@POST 
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String showTime(
    @FormParam("username") String userName,
    @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest
) {
    // The method body
}
```

Comment: Thanks sdorra that seems to do the trick. One last question, (can open this as a new question if needs be) how would i access the request body itself?

Comment: The body is controlled by the @Consumes Annotation:

`@Path("body")
public class BodyResource
{
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String get(String body)
  {
    System.out.println(body);
    return "The Body: ".concat(body);
  }
}`

Comment: if you are using maven you should have a dependency for:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the request body, you could use the tip lined out in this post: [How to get full REST request body using Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725315/how-to-get-full-rest-request-body-using-jersey)

If you need to know more about the request itself, you could try the @Context annotation as mentioned by sdorra.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a helper function to address this. Simply extracts request headers and places them in a map.

```
private Map<String, String> extractHeaders(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String header = headerNames.nextElement();
        map.put(header, httpServletRequest.getHeader(header));
    }

    return map;
}
```