# Session creation and management

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, session

How and when does a session gets created?

If I am hitting a request to the website, what will be the session scope?

When I submit a request for login will it create a new session?

When dropdowns or any other operations on the JSP and making an ajax call will it create a new session every time when I make an ajax call?

Comment: In PHP, there is a command `session_start`. I imagine there must be something similar in Java.

Comment: And here's the answer to my conjecture. Might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826643/java-equivalent-of-session-start-session-destroy-and-sessionusername