# Parse request parameters without writing wrapper class

Tags: jersey, dropwizard, pojo

How to handle json requests and parse the request parameters in dropWizard?

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String test(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
    JSONObject data=new JSONObject();
    System.out.println(request);
    System.out.println(request.getParameterMap());
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>");

    return "{\"status\":\"ok\"}";
}
```

I wrote the above code and tried the following request.

```
curl -XPOST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data {"field1":"val1", "field2":"val2"} http://localhost:8080/test
```

But `request.getParameterMap()` is `{}`

How to parse the parameters without writing a wrapper class?

Answer (score 0):

Your `curl` command may need some additional quotes around the data (I'm getting an error without them):

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"field1":"tal1", "field2":"val2"}' http://localhost:8080/test
```

You are sending a `POST` request **without** `URL` parameters. I'm not sure why you are expecting to see something there.

I don't know which version of `dropwizard` you are using but I couldn't make the combination of `@POST` and `@Path("/something")` annotation to behave when a method is annotated. I'm getting `HTTP ERROR 404`.

To make it work I have to move the `@Path` annotation to the resource/class level and leave only the `@Post` annotation at the method.

```
@Path("/test")
public class SimpleResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test(final String data) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("And now the request body:");
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>");

        return "{\"status\":\"ok\"}";
    }
}
```

To get the body of the request as `String` just do as above. Taken from here: [How to get full REST request body using Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725315/how-to-get-full-rest-request-body-using-jersey)

The console looks like:

```
INFO  [2016-11-24 15:26:29,290] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @3539ms
And now the request body:
{"field1":"tal1", "field2":"val2"}
>>>>>>>>>
```