# put and post method dropwizard-auth-jwt

Tags: authentication, jwt, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I implemented Resful application using [dropwizard framework](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/getting-started.html).  I use dropwizard-auth-jwt for my authentication with maven package:

> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.github.toastshaman</groupId>
>   <artifactId>dropwizard-auth-jwt</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0.2-0 </version> 
>   </dependency>

for adding authentication for resources, I implemented sampleAuthenticator which is implemented Authenticator class that uses Principal class for it's authentication check.

```
public class UserAuthenticate implements Authenticator &ltJwtContext, MyUser> {

    @Override
    public Optional&ltMyUser> authenticate(JwtContext context) {
        try {
            final String subject = context.getJwtClaims().getSubject();
            if ("authentication".equals(subject)) {
                return Optional.of(new MyUser("admin", "pass"));
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        catch (MalformedClaimException e) { return Optional.empty(); }
    }
}
```

when MyUser implemented Principal:

```
public class MyUser implements Principal {

    private  String pass;
    private  String name;

    public MyUser(String name, String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public MyUser( String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public MyUser(){}

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyUser{" +
                "pass='" + pass + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        final MyUser myUser = (MyUser) o;
        return Objects.equals(pass, myUser.pass) && Objects.equals(name, myUser.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(pass, name);
    }
}
```

with this configurations, I needed add resource for crud operations. for get and delete there is no probelm. but when I add post or put when needs to add new object for body of request, I have error.

post:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
public Response create(@Auth MyUser admin, Body body) {
   return Response
           .status(Response.Status.OK)
           .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           .entity(true)
           .build();
}
```

error:

> Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException:
>   Validation of the application resource model has failed during
>   application initialization. [[FATAL] No injection source found for a
>   parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   myGroup.resources.BodyResource.create(myGroup.api.MyUser,myGroup.api.Body)
>   at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST,
>   consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[application/json],
>   suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS,
>   invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class
>   myGroup.resources.BodyResource,
>   handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@20411320]},
>   definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   myGroup.resources.BodyResource.create(myGroup.api.MyUser,myGroup.api.Body),
>   parameters=[Parameter [type=class myGroup.api.MyUser, source=null,
>   defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class myGroup.api.Body,
>   source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] The
>   (sub)resource method create in myGroup.resources.BodyResource contains
>   empty path annotation.; source='public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   myGroup.resources.BodyResource.create(myGroup.api.MyUser,myGroup.api.Body)'

Answer (score 1):

`Jersey` wants the `@Path` annotation to be at class level. See my answer here: [Parse request parameters without writing wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784962/parse-request-parameters-without-writing-wrapper-class/40790052#40790052)

> I don't know which version of dropwizard you are using but I couldn't
>   make the combination of @POST and @Path("/something") annotation to
>   behave when a method is annotated. I'm getting HTTP ERROR 404.

Comment: tnx. I have it but I think problem is with dropwizard-auth-jwt. As I said, I have get and delete methods without any error but when I add post or put, jersey says the error in initialization

Comment: I used dropwizard 1.0.5

Comment: As I said, I think the problem is with dropwizard-auth-jwt and because of that I use https://github.com/milpol/jwt-dropwizard instead.