# How is data from HTTP request body passed into a servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I'm new to Java web programming, and I was reading the following piece of code which uses Spring and swagger. I could not understand how the `jsonRequestBody` parameter was populated with data from the HTTP POST request body. I read from somewhere that the `@RequestBody` annotation should be used to read the request body, much like how you use `@PathParam` and `@QueryParam`, but it is not used in this case. How did Spring figure out how to parse the HTTP request body and put it in `jsonRequestBody`?

```
    @POST
    @Path("{transactionId}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update Running balances for Journal Entries", notes = "This API calculates the running balances for office. If office ID not provided this API calculates running balances for all offices. \n" + "Mandatory Fields\n" + "officeId")
    @ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(paramType = "body", value = "body", dataType = "body", dataTypeClass = JournalEntriesApiResourceSwagger.PostJournalEntriesTransactionIdRequest.class)})
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = JournalEntriesApiResourceSwagger.PostJournalEntriesTransactionIdResponse.class)})
    public String createReversalJournalEntry(@ApiParam(hidden = true) final String jsonRequestBody, @PathParam("transactionId") @ApiParam(value = "transactionId") final String transactionId,
            @QueryParam("command") @ApiParam(value = "command") final String commandParam) {
    //.... 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer here at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1773308/9867856. It turns out that as long as the method is marked with @POST, the method's String parameter will be automatically populated with data from the request body.