# Non-annotated param of resource GET method

Tags: java, jax-rs

There are multiple annotations in JAX-RS method params: `@QueryParam`, `@PathParam`, etc.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html

However, these annotations are not mandatory. I have a situation when a parameter of GET method is not annotated:

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Map<String, Object> getProduct(
      String domain,
      @QueryParam("code") String code,
      @QueryParam("region") String region
  ) {
```

Here **domain** parameter is not annotated at all. I’m not sure what it means. (It is a production code from some repository).

For POST methods this would mean that domain parameter would consume request body: [How to get full REST request body using Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725315/how-to-get-full-rest-request-body-using-jersey)

But what it would mean for GET method? As far as I know body does not make much sense for GET requests (i.e., it can be safely ignored according to web standard).

What is the default fallback for unannotated parameters? I did not find the answer in documentation.

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Comment: This was the production code that I’ve encountered in one of work projects. In theory I could simplify, run and debug it, but regardless of result, I still want to find some sort of ‘official confirmation’ of how it should work (e.g. documentation reference).

Comment: I can tell you that on the Jersey client side, when you try to send a GET request with a body, you get an "HTTP non-compliance error". I forgot on the server side, but there might have been a warning if not an error. Other implementations might be different. The semantics of the non-annotated parameter is always to be the body.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a corner case due to the fact that HTTP specification ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3) at least) [does not explicitly forbid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) a body being present in a GET request.

On the other hand, JAX-RS ([JSR311](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr311/index.html)) is very specific in 3.3.2.1:

> The value of a non-annotated parameter, called the entity parameter, is mapped from the request entity body.
> Conversion between an entity body and a Java type is the responsibility of an entity provider, see section 4.2. 
> Resource methods MUST NOT have more than one parameter that is not annotated with one of the above-
> listed annotations.

So, to finally answer your question:
Assuming your implementation accepts a GET request with a body (highly unlikely, based on my experience), JAX-RS *should* try to read it into the `domain` parameter.

However, I'd expect that `domain` would be `null`, since `GET` requests don't usually have a body, so with proper `null` handling of the parameter, this behavior can easily go undetected.